# Session Timeout creation for application

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a requirement for session timeout. This is my requirement. Once logged in to my application, a time count sholud start. If it reaches 10 mins, it should gives a alert which prompting as

> do you want to continue?

If customer press "Yes" the session should continue and time resetted as 0. If press "No", the session should close and error page need to come. I need this changes in javascript and jsp. Can any one have idea about this?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` function in JS

Comment: Alerk am using frameset. On Page load i gave the frame set. On each time loading the frame it is resetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your frameset file, you can have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout('checkIfContinue()', 10*60*1000);  //10 minutes

    function checkIfContinue()
    {
        if(confirm("Do you want to continue?"))
        {
            window.setTimeout('checkIfContinue()', 10*60*1000);  //start the timer again
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = 'timeout.html';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Of course, if you need a fancy dialog box, then you'll need to code that instead of using javascript function `confirm`.

Comment: This will wait ten minutes from the time the page is loaded, rather than ten minutes from the time the session started.  So if a user goes to page 1 and is there for five minutes, then page 2, and is there for five minutes, the timeout will not occur.

Comment: @dnuttle: I don't think 10 minutes from the beginning of the session is a reasonable (or even valid) requirement.  Term "timeout" usually mean "from the last user action".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a complete code example.  But briefly, I would say that you should use ajax on the client side to ping the server once a minute or so, to see if the timeout has expired.  But then, if it has, there's a challenge.  The server tells the client, "the session has expired," but then what?  If the user doesn't respond with "yes," you want the session to timeout?  If so, then how long does the server wait to hear back from the client before timing out?  What if the user doesn't click "yes" for 30 seconds?  So it can get sticky, and you would have to decide on the rules.

If no action is taken unless the user clicks "no" then this isn't a problem.

However I should also say that I don't think it's a good idea to ask visitors if they want to continue.  It makes visitors feel like they are being pestered to leave.

Comment: This comment is useful for me as business logical